# What is the proper way to add an object multiple textures that ı download from Sketchfab

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I  am in early stages of learning unity. So my queiston is how can ı add multiple textures to one complex object. I know that ı should create material and attach texture into it but how could ı know that material should be attached which part of character. Is there any way get this done by easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Examine the hierarchy of the 3d model (there can be one or more with children etc..). There should be a MeshRenderer component attached to some game objects (see components in the inspector when a game object is selected). For a MeshRenderer there is a list of materials and you can change them by referencing other from the project.